# Detail View is not updated when the model is updated (Using List) SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, swiftui-list

I am using **List** to show the models in the main view. When I update the model in detail view it is not updated in detail view.

When I don't use `List`, detail view is updated. What am I missing for `List`?

---

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
  var id: UUID
  var name: String
}

class PersonModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var persons: [Person] = [Person(id: UUID(), name: "Ege")]
}

struct PersonListView: View {
  
  @StateObject private var personModel = PersonModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(personModel.persons) { person in
          NavigationLink(destination: PersonDetailView(person: person).environmentObject(personModel)) {
            Text(person.name)
          }
        }
      }
      .navigationTitle("Persons")
    }
  }
}

struct PersonDetailView: View {
  
  let person: Person
  @EnvironmentObject var personModel: PersonModel
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(person.name)
      
      Button(action: {
        let personIndex = personModel.persons.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == person.id })!
        personModel.persons[personIndex].name = "Updated Name"
      }) {
        Text("Update")
      }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Person Detail")
  }
}
```

Workarounds that I used for List:

- Using custom binding function for NavigationLink.

Example code:

```
//1
private func binding(for person: Person) -> Binding<Person> {
  let personIndex = personModel.persons.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == person.id }) ?? 0
  return $personModel.persons[personIndex]
}
//2
NavigationLink(destination: PersonDetailView(person: binding(for: person)))
//3
@Binding var person: Person //DetailView
```

- Using another `@State` in detail view which is initialized with passed
  model in onAppear method.

Comment: It works for me 

Comment: @Mecid Are you sure you are only using the first code snippet, since others are workarounds? For me it does not work, i am sure. Also I  am using Xcode 12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed in Xcode 13 Beta.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that, although your workaround surely works, you'd like to know what's happening and why you need a workaround in the first place.

When you update the value of your `@Published var persons: [Person]` array, your detail view is re-rendered as you would expect. But you are telling your view to print the `name` value of the `var person: Person` struct which hasn't changed. It's still the same as when the view was first created.

If you replace

```
Text(person.name)
```

with

```
Text(personModel.persons.first(where: { $0.id == person.id } )!.name)
```

it updates as you would expect, because you're providing the Text view with the `name` value of the new version of `person` pulled from your actual `PersonModel` that you just updated.

So the involvement of `List` doesn't seem to be the issue, which is why I haven't directly answered your question "What am I missing for `List`?". Hopefully it helps anyway!

Comment: I know It willl work with that way but what I am trying to figure out / what I am asking is actually why my detail view is re-rendered if I don't use `List`(Try to replace the `List` with another stacks like `VStack`, you will see It will working without no changes in other code).

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

You can send manual changes but you need to use class instead of struct for the model.
Like this

```
Button(action: {
    if let personIndex = personModel.persons.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == person.id }) { //<==Here
        personModel.persons[personIndex].name = "Updated Name"
        personModel.objectWillChange.send() //<==Here
    }
    
})
```

---

The possible solution is to update your data and reassign elements to the array.

```
struct PersonDetailView: View {
    
    let person: Person
    @EnvironmentObject var personModel: PersonModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(person.name)
            
            Button(action: {
                if let personIndex = personModel.persons.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == person.id }) { //<==Here
                    personModel.persons[personIndex].name = "Updated Name"
                    personModel.persons[personIndex] = personModel.persons[personIndex]
                }
                
            }) {
                Text("Update")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Person Detail")
    }
}
```

And use class

```
class Person: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also explain why do I need to use class instead of struct and notify the observable object with `personModel.objectWillChange.send()` when using **List**.

Comment: @egeeke I used class because I use reference. it will update in all. and for ```personModel.objectWillChange.send()``` this is for update the whole view. Since your details view is not dependent on any state or binding object. Also when you used without a list that means your row is part of the same view.

Comment: "personModel.objectWillChange.send() //<==Here" worked perfectly for me with a very similar problem. Thank you, Raja Kishan!