# SwiftUI @Published property not updating views

Tags: ios, swiftui, reactive-programming

In the code below, the detail view UI does not update when the FavoriteButton is tapped.  We know the binding is connected to the ObservableObject because the `didSet` is called and prints the updated state of the `foos` array.  Oddly, I found that adding a `VStack` in the `FooList`'s `NavigationView` resolves the bug in this instance, but did not for the more complicated UI where I encountered this issue.

Am I missing something about how this should be connected?  Another workaround is to toggle a `State` bool in the `FavoriteButton`, but that seems like it goes against the point of Bindings.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Foo: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
}

class FooData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foos = [Foo(name: "Test", isFavorite: true)] {
        didSet {
            print(foos)
        }
    }
}

struct FooList: View {
    @ObservedObject var fooData = FooData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
// Adding a VStack makes the FavoriteButton update correctly, but this doesn't work for more complicated UIs
//            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(fooData.foos, id: \.id) { foo in
                        let index = fooData.foos.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == foo.id })!
                        NavigationLink(foo.name, destination: FooDetailView(foo: $fooData.foos[index]))
                    }
                }
//            }
        }
    }
}

struct FooDetailView: View {
    @Binding var foo: Foo
    
    var body: some View {
        FavoriteButton(isFavorite: $foo.isFavorite)
    }
}

struct FavoriteButton: View {
    @Binding var isFavorite: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isFavorite.toggle()
        }, label: {
            if isFavorite {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### UPDATE:

Passing `FooData` as an `EnvironmentObject` to the `List` and declaring the `EnvironmentObject` in the `FavoriteButton` resolves the issue.  This must be sufficient to tell SwiftUI that this View cares about any updates to the `FooData`, even if no code references the `EnvironmentObject` directly.  This feels a little like magic, definitely not the most intuitive behavior for me.  Hopefully, this can help someone else.

Full working code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Foo: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
}

class FooData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foos = [Foo(name: "Test", isFavorite: true)] {
        didSet {
            print(foos)
        }
    }
}

struct FooList: View {
    @ObservedObject var fooData = FooData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fooData.foos, id: \.id) { foo in
                    let index = fooData.foos.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == foo.id })!
                    NavigationLink(foo.name, destination: FooDetailView(foo: $fooData.foos[index]))
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(fooData)
    }
}

struct FooDetailView: View {
    @Binding var foo: Foo
    
    var body: some View {
        FavoriteButton(isFavorite: $foo.isFavorite)
    }
}

struct FavoriteButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var fooData: FooData
    @Binding var isFavorite: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isFavorite.toggle()
        }, label: {
            if isFavorite {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141387/detail-view-is-not-updated-when-the-model-is-updated-using-list-swiftui this problem looks like the problem I have had. Is not it?

Comment: @egeeke, very similar yes.  I think the difference in mine is that I'm passing in the binding directly with `$fooData.foos[index]`, and the detail view is still not updating.  You're totally right that it's `List` related, If I remove that and just use a `ForEach`, then the detail view updates correctly.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a viewModel Publishing an array the only thing that can trigger a view update is the array count. So you need to make the objects in the array a `class`, extend it to `ObservableObject`, and make `isFavorite` an `@Published var` it will work.

```
class Foo: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  var id = UUID()
  var name: String
  @Published var isFavorite: Bool

  init(name: String, isFavorite: Bool) {
    self.name = name
    self.isFavorite = isFavorite
  }
}
```

Also, you should make your `FooData` an `@StateObject` as this view owns it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var fooData = FooData()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(fooData.foos) { foo in
          NavigationLink(foo.name, destination: FooDetailView(foo: foo))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pass the `foo` down as an `@ObservedObject`

```
struct FooDetailView: View {
  @ObservedObject var foo: Foo

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        foo.isFavorite.toggle()
    }, label: {
        if foo.isFavorite {
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
        } else {
            Image(systemName: "heart")
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered that approach.  The publisher for `FooData` won't see any of those updates if `Foo` is a class, though.  I've tried to add a View Model that publishes a `Foo`, but I can't find a way without using Combine to connect it to `FooData`.

Comment: Foo does not need to adopted to ObservableObject  to make isFavorite a @Published var.

Comment: Ahmad, but if it's not an ObservaleObject it can't be Observed in the View. Yes, Xcode will let you set the property as @Published but the view will not change.

Comment: Whatever you need Foo just put it as an @ObservedObject in a View and it will.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using an intermediate "wrapper" for the `NavigationLink` view that still has access to the `ObservableObject`:

```
struct FooList: View {
    @ObservedObject var fooData = FooData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(fooData.foos, id: \.id) { foo in
                        NavigationLink(foo.name, destination: FooWrapper(id: foo.id, fooData: fooData))
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct FooWrapper : View {
    var id : UUID
    @ObservedObject var fooData : FooData
    
    var fooBinding : Binding<Foo> {
        .init { () -> Foo in
            let index = fooData.foos.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
            return fooData.foos[index]
        } set: { (newValue) in
            let index = fooData.foos.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
            fooData.foos[index] = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        FooDetailView(foo: fooBinding)
    }
}
```

I reused your code for finding the `index` of `foo` -- personally, I'd probably write a solution without the force unwrap in the event of a crash, but that's an issue not completely related to the question.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of a custom binding.  I like how the dependencies are still the same as in the original code.  Makes sense to use the ID to connect them.  Is there a fundamental reason why this kind of workaround is necessary, or should I expect that a SwiftUI update might fix this later down the line?

Comment: I assume that it has to do with some sort of optimizations that `List` tries to do (presumably for lists with tons of items), but I don't know if that'll last forever or not.